# The Image Optimization Framework was not initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sprite

I am having this error `The Image Optimization Framework was not initialized. Verify the sprites directory exists. After creating the directory, restart the site or application.`

The error is in this method `Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizations.EnsureInitialized()` but I do have an App_Sprites directory and i have restarted several times, casini and IIS. I updated from version 0.3 to 0.4.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

I am using AspNetSprites-MvcAndRazorHelpers

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: I couldn't maybe is a bug from the framework, I return to version 0.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and probably the reason was that the folder `App_Sprites` was marked as read-only. Since my project was on source control, I either have to check it out or try a hackish way which is remove the read-only attribute from the folder.

So right click on `App_Sprites` folder -> Open folder in windows explorer -> Right click -> Properties -> Removed read-only

Also I check under the Security tab to see if I have enough permissions to write to the folder.

After all that I did a clean and Re-build and was able to build the application successfully.